# best practice for nonexistent values in json object / mongodb object schema?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, schema, mongoose-schema

I am planning the schema for some objects to eventually be saved in a MongoDB collection. The objects I generate now are the output from a server app.

```
              "release-data": [
                {
                  "community": {
                    "have": 13,
                    "want": 8
                  },
                  "marketplace": {
                    "num_for_sale": null,
                    "lowest_price": null
                  },
                  "date": "2022-3-21 20:30:8"
                }
              ],
              "price-suggestions": [
                {
                  "prices": {},
                  "date": "2022-3-21 20:30:8"
                }
              ]
```

I am wondering if the best practice for the above fields which have no value would be `null` or empty object. Or maybe the `marketplace` field itself is assigned null or an empty object in this case?

I was considering a minimal approach where in this example the `marketplace` field in the `release-data` array would not exist and same thing with the `prices` field in the `price-suggestions` array not existing. But is that considered a bad practice since it is impossible to tell if the data is truly nonexistent or was omitted in error?

Is there anything else I may not be considering?

Comment: MongoDB allows flexible schema - that is documents can have different fields. It mostly depends upon your application functionality to have empty/null/non-existing fields. Some points to note: Do your queries need to show that, for example, a certain field's value is null or empty or zero? How will you update data into these empty/null/non-existing fields later? That said, the MogoDB Query Language and Aggregation Framework has operators to check if a field is null/empty/not-exists during update / query operations...

Comment: ...  Another point is that a empty/null field/value occupies space - consider this for very large collections.